# How to make a filetype plugin mapping override a global plugin mapping?

Tags: vim

I have a defined a mapping in a global plugin file:

```
inoremap { {<CR><CR>}<Up>
```

and I want to override it in only one filetype plugin file using:

```
inoremap { {}<Left>
```

But vim only uses the first mapping, rather than overriding it with the second. How can I make it work?

I know I can just define a file-specific mapping in my .vimrc but I would prefer not to do it that way

Comment: See the post glts refers to. Make sure you use `<buffer>` option in your mapping. Vim use use the most specific mapping.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate as the OP in the question glts refers to had no global mappings. Any way the answer is indeed to the make the mapping buffer-local with ... `<buffer>`

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options :

1. Define your filetype specific mapping in a ftplugin/filetype.vim file.
2. Define your filetype specific mapping in your vimrc, using an autocmd for FileType event.

I tend to prefer the first option, since that keeps the code much cleaner in your vimrc.

Comment: OP's issue is about the `<buffer>` specifier that he forgot to add.